# How to get current user's data in Controller's constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to use some current user's data in controller's constructor to initialize repositories, but looks like impossible to get current user's data, because all objects, which can give any data about the user (for example `HttpContext` or `User`) is nullable in constructor's area. How can I get needed data inside the constructor or any other way initialize repositories with user's data?

Comment: Why do you need that in the *constructor* ? You don't need to initialize the repositories in the constructor, you can do so in the action. You don't need to know the user to connect to a database, you only need the id to pass it as a parameter to a query

Comment: is this for asp.net 5 or for asp.net core?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos 1. The problem is, that web-application is already written, I just try to improve it. One of controllers, for example, has maybe more than 100 actionss and create all 17 repositories in every method is hard and not right. 2. But even ID is unavailable in constructor (if I mistake, show me where).

Comment: @jao asp.net core 1.1, but the same problem (User data unavailability), as I remember, exists in clasical asp.net mvc too (at least in 4-th version)

Comment: Then you have a design problem and misunderstand what controllers and repositories are about.. The *constructor* is called when the controller is *constructed*. It hasn't become part of the pipeline yet. What is not right is trying to grab *request* data when there's no request to use. A controller with 100 actions isn't. It's 50-100 controllers thrown into a single source file.

Comment: Finally, an action that needs **17** repositories - why? Aren't you using an ORM? Shouldn't you be able to load only 1 or 2 root objects and have *them* load their entire graph? Sounds like you replicated your database schema into code and renamed tables as repositories. Probably use a lot of joins to combine objects too?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I have the same questions to application creator :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IHttpContextAccessor` to access `HttpContext` in constructor;

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
}
```

If you are using ASP.NET Core 1.x register `IHttpContextAccessor` in configure method in startup class and for ASP.NET Core 2.0 I think it is not required.

```
services.TryAddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why in the constructor?

There are four ways you can get the current user's data in MVC:

1. You can create a session for the current user's data (preferred)
2. You can store data in local storage.
3. Using cookies. But that depends on cookies being allowed in the user's browser.
4. MVC provides ViewBag. You can pass data by using it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting user data in a cookie. Doesn't sound like a secure way.

Comment: Yupp , me too. But I only show the way to pass user data. @jao

Comment: Using session to put some data, when log in - it can be a solution. Thanks for good advice